# How to convert ref byte into byte[]?

Tags: c#, binary

Have anyone had an experience in converting `ref byte` into `byte[]`?

If the function takes an argument like

```
void foo(ref byte buffer);
```

then it is possible to call `foo` using

```
void call_func()
{
    byte arr[] = new byte[10];
    foo(ref arr[0]);
}
```

The question is how can one re-convert the `buffer` argument into `byte[]` array in the `foo`.

Comment: If you need to pass an array, why not pass an array? C# is not C.

Comment: You should drop some of yours c/c++ habits already...

Comment: @khkarens: C++/CLI works much much better for letting C# call existing C++ code than SWiG.

Comment: The memory allocation of the array type is an implementation detail you shouldn't rely upon.

Comment: The initial purpose of this byte conversion is to pass the C# buffer into C++, SWIG has a functionality which allows exposing methods with signed bytes interface, something like 
    void foo(ref sbyte buffer)
however, I need to expose another method with the following interface
    void foo(ref byte buffer)
hence, I want to hide the necessary conversion from byte[] buffer into sbyte[] in C# side (this can be achieved with the following code:
    byte arr[] = new byte[10];
    sbyte[] signed = (sbyte[])(Array)arr;
though, in order to hide this conversion I hit to the issue above.

Comment: `byte[]` and `sbyte[]` are supposed to be [assignment compatible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx), you shouldn't need a cast.  See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't.

In order to avoid pinning the entire array, the runtime might just make a copy of the single element you selected (and then copy back after the call).  In that case your function will get the address of a temporary copy, which is unrelated to the address of the other array elements.  (Well, [there could be some aliasing considerations](http://ideone.com/EpzCF), this optimization is much more likely for pinvoke and/or remote calls, where aliasing analysis is more feasible)

If you need an array, pass the array.

---

If you don't care that it might not work right, you can use unsafe code to get to the other elements.

```
pinned( byte* p = &buffer ) {
    buffer[4] = 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 and you'll mess up the brain of anyone trying to debug your code if you did

Comment: Thank you @BenVoigt!
Seems I have a reason to investigate the behavior of swig (to understand why is exposes ref sbyte instead of ref sbyte[] from unsigned char*). The explanation is clear.

Comment: Ben, the definition of [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) in C# seems to be contradictory to what you explained. They say that _The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the parameter in the method is reflected in the underlying argument variable in the calling method._ therefore I'm not getting how can optimizer kick out the idea of reference and pass a temporary value?

Comment: @khkarens: That's related to the aliasing analysis I mentioned.  If the compiler can prove that there is no concurrent access to the same location, it can operate on a copy (for example, if the array was just allocated and no other references to it have been stored, then the compiler can prove that aliasing isn't possible).  Also under some circumstances, that guarantee is not made (remote procedure calls, for example, always operate on a temporary copy).  Cache coherency comes into play as well.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thank you for clarification! However, I still feel some difficulties about that: if _ref_ was something similar to _const&_ in C++ I wouldn't bother myself with curiosity. Nevertheless, how can compiler prove that the referenced _ref byte[0]_ attribute won't be modified in the called function? Do you think it is possible that compiler can pass a copy of a single byte to the function and rewrite the content of the temporary copy of the byte into the buffer after function returns?

Comment: @khkarens: That's what my answer says.... "and then copy back after the call".  But it can only do that when it can prove aliasing doesn't occur.  Actually, it probably only will look for ways to use a copy when doing p/invoke, since a native pointer requires pinning.  A simple C# byref doesn't require pinning so using a copy is unlikely.  But all these details can change between .NET versions, so relying on the unsafe code is not recommended.